# Add and Remove HTA components dynamically

Tags: hta

Can anybody help me how to remove textboxes dynamically in HTA?

This code *adds* textboxes dynamically:

```
Sub AddTextBox
    strHTML = DataArea.InnerHTML strHTML=strHTML&"<tr><td>Source Path</td><td><input type="&Chr(34)& _ "text"&Chr(34)&">"&"</td><td><button type="&Chr(34)&"button"&Chr(34)& _ "onclick="&Chr(34)&"RemoveTextBox"&Chr(34)&">"&"x"&"</button></td></tr>"
    DataArea.InnerHTML = strHTML
    tabHTML = tabHTML & strHTML
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the whole `tr` or the `input` only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is similar to what you are looking for, this will at least give you a working example you can build from. The `Window_OnLoad` subroutine loads the initial content then the newly created content contains a button which when clicked removes the textbox/button and adds a new button labeled `Add Again?`. This new button can call the `Window_OnLoad` subroutine again and reload the original content.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dynamically Add Controls</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Dynamically Add Controls"
  ID="Dynamically_Add_Controls"
  VERSION="1.0"/>
</head>

<script language="VBScript">

Sub Window_OnLoad
    strHTML = "<tr><td>Source Path</td><td><input type="& Chr(34)& "text"&Chr(34)&">"&"</td><td><button type="&Chr(34)&"button"&Chr(34)& "onclick="&Chr(34)&"RemoveTextBox"&Chr(34)&">"&"Remove All?"&"</button></td></tr>"
    DataArea.InnerHTML = strHTML
End Sub

Sub RemoveTextBox()
    strHTML = "<td><button type="&Chr(34)&"button"&Chr(34)& "onclick="&Chr(34)&"Window_OnLoad"&Chr(34)&">"&"Add Again?"&"</button></td></tr>"
    DataArea.InnerHTML = strHTML
End Sub

</script>

<body bgcolor="white">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"><Div id="DataArea"></Div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```